# compare values, sort them and determine which is more favorable

Tags: mysql, sql

To get started, I have a database based on sports betting. I have one table called 'MATCHES' (id_match / sport_id / League_id /team / rival / result ).

The query that I am using is the following:

```
SELECT leagues.name,
   COUNT(matches.League_id) AS times_bet,
   COUNT(case when matches.result = 'W' then 1 else null end) AS times_won,
   AVG (matches.result = 'W')*100 AS winrate,
   nations.name as nation,
   sports.name as sport
   FROM matches,leagues,sports,nations
   WHERE matches.League_id=leagues.id and leagues.Sport_id=sports.id and 
   leagues.Nation_id=nations.id
   GROUP BY matches.League_id
```

And the results that I am generating:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------+ 
| name | times_bet | times_won | winrate | nation | sport |  
+---------------------------------------------------------+ 
|  xxx |   100     |     65    |   65%   |  xxxxx |  xxx  |
|  aaa |   70      |     49    |   70%   |  bbbbb |  ccc  |
|  yyy |   65      |     50    |   77%   |  bbbbb |  ccc  |
|  eee |   7       |     7     |   100%  |  ppppp |  hhh  |
```

The problem comes when I try to find out what league is more favorable.

If I order the query by winrate and time_bets, the most favorable league would be the last one, and that's not what I want.

I want to find out if there is any way to be able to compare the amount of predictions together with their winrate and thus be able to determine which league is the most favorable of all.

A league with 50 predictions and 80% winrate is more favorable than one that has 5 predictions with 100% winrate. This is what I mean.

I will give a graphic example of what I would like to see:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------+ 
| name | times_bet | times_won | winrate | nation | sport |  
+---------------------------------------------------------+ 
|  yyy |   65      |     50    |   77%   |  bbbbb |  ccc  |
|  aaa |   70      |     49    |   70%   |  bbbbb |  ccc  |
|  xxx |   100     |     65    |   65%   |  xxxxx |  xxx  |
|  eee |   7       |     7     |   100%  |  ppppp |  hhh  |
```

If anyone knows any way to do it, I would be grateful. Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't rely on functional dependencies. If a non-aggregated column appears in the SELECT, include it in the GROUP BY. And we stopped writing queries ca. 1992. Come. JOIN us.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mcve]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & clear specification & explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly you mean by "more favorable"?

For example if we assume that all bets have exactly the same odds if a player distributed the amount he wants to bet equally among all bets of that league then the most favorable would be the one with the highest winning rate.

But if a player put a fixed amount in every bet then things change.

For example if we assume that in all bets odds for winning are 2.00 so for every dollar you bet you get 2 dollars back when you win,  then if a player put one dollar for every game in every league, the more favorable league for him would be yyy because he would have got back 2*50=100 dollars with total bets of 65 dollars, so he would have 35 dollars profit from that league. Although league eee has higher winning rate it has significant less bets, so he would have got back 2*7=14 dollars from 7 dollar total bets for a total profit of only 7 dollars.

In the example I assumed that the average bet odds for winning predictions is a fixed number and the same for every league. Which obviously is not the case.You should find the average odds of the winning predictions for every league.For example if a league has three winning predictions with odds 2.00,3.00 and 4.00 respectively you should take the average which is (2+3+4)/3=3 and use that value.

Something like this:

`ORDER BY (times_won*avg_odds_of_winning_predictions)-times_bet DESC`

Comment: "ORDER BY (times_won*AVG(quota_league))-times_bet DESC".  That has helped me a lot. Very thankful :D

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to the end of the query:

```
ORDER BY times_bet*winrate DESC
```

This order the output by the expression in descending order.